# JavaScript for loop

Tags: javascript

i don't know why my code doesn't run,someone can help me?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    excerise
    </title>
    <style></style>
    </head>
    <body>


<script>
    function multiple ( )
var i=0;
for (i=pooya;i<=5;i++)
{
 document.getElementById("pooya").innerHTML = i;
}
    }
    
</script>
number<br>
<input type="text" id="pooya">
        <button onclick=" multiple ()">try it</button>
<p>Explanation:</p>

<p>This for loop starts with i=0.</p>

<p>As long as <b>i</b> is less than, or equal to 5, the loop will continue to run.</p>

<p><b>i</b> will increase by 1 each time the loop runs.</p>
        
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("pooya").value = i;`

Comment: Don't repeat the same sentence over and over it doesn't help in the least. Describe what you are trying to do, and what problems you are experiencing

Comment: try `document.getElementById("pooya").value += i;`

Comment: There’s a missing `{`. Next time make sure you don’t have typo errors like these by using [JSHint](http://jshint.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does not run because of the following issues

`function multiple ( )`. Though there is a closing `}` but there is no opening `{` which mark the start of function body.
  The function body should be inside `{ }` . Example

```
function multiple() { //Rest of code}
```

`for (i=pooya;i<=5;i++){}`. This part will not work. pooya is a an id to an element & if you are assigning it to a `i`. If you want to do that initialize `pooya` with some value

`document.getElementById("pooya").innerHTML` = i . Are you trying to update the input box? If so then you have to use `document.getElementById("pooya").value = i`

In this case you will always see `5` as updated value in input box.

If you do `document.getElementById("pooya").innerHTML` += i`you will see 
"entered value"+12345;
Example:If you give input as`4`the input box will be updated with`4012345`

Check this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/xx06nsfs/1/)

**EDIT**

```
function multiple ( ){
var i= document.getElementById("pooya").value;  // Will take the entered value
document.getElementById("pooya").value=""; // will empty the inpt
for(i;i<=5;i++){ 
 document.getElementById("pooya").value += i; // will update input box

  }
}
```

[Updated jsFidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/xx06nsfs/2/)

Comment: yes  but my output should be like if i enter 3 the box updated like 345

Comment: @PooyaMahmoodi check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

1) Youre Missing a { after your "multiple()".  It needs the beginning { to be properly formatted.

2) You need to get grab the value of "pooya" before you use it.
do this.

```
 <script>
    //<![CDATA[
    function multiple(){
        var pooya = document.getElementById("pooya").value;
        for (i=pooya;i<6;i++)
        {
         alert("testing");
        }
    }
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow questions that are based on simple typos shouldn’t be answered but flagged or voted to close (or closed and ultimately deleted). Since you don’t have the flagging privilege yet, you just shouldn’t have answered.